# WPF XAML Parse exception occur

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a Wpf application ,the application starts fine with a splash screen than introduction page but than as i click on next it gives me following Exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in    PresentationFramework.dll.
```

Following is my xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AFICController.View.DiscoverConnectDevice"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:res="clr-namespace:AFICController.Resources"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:AFICController.View"
             >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock
      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5"
      FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="12" Foreground="Black"  Opacity="0.8"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Visibility="{Binding DeviceDiscoveryString1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
      >
      Let's discover the active<Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="ARC"
         /><Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript" Text="®"/><Run Text="Access Point."/>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock
      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5"
      FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="12" Foreground="Black"  Opacity="0.8"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Visibility="{Binding DeviceDiscoveryString2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
      >Discovering connected  active<Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="ARC"
         /><Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript" Text="®"/><Run Text="Access Point ...." />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5,5,5,0"
      FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="12" Foreground="Black"  Opacity="0.8"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Visibility="{Binding DeviceDiscoveryString3, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
      >
      No active<Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="ARC"
         /><Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript" Text="®"/><Run Text="Access Point found." />
      <LineBreak/>
       Verify connections and click on 'Let's Discover'.
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock
      Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,5,0"
      FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="12" Foreground="Black"  Opacity="0.8"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Visibility="{Binding DeviceDiscoveryString4, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
      >
      If problems persist, please contact active<Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="ARC"
         /><Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript" Text="®"/><Run 
                  Text=" support at 855.MYARC11 (855.692.7211) or support@activearc.att-mail.com."/>

        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock
      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5"
      FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="12" Foreground="Black"  Opacity="0.8"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Text="ARC1000MAP Discovered."
      Visibility="{Binding DeviceDiscoveryString5, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
      />

        <TextBlock
      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5"
      FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="12" Foreground="Black"  Opacity="0.8"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Text="ARC2000MAP Discovered."
      Visibility="{Binding DeviceDiscoveryString6, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
      />

        <TextBlock
      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5"
      FontFamily="Arial"  FontSize="12" Foreground="Black"  Opacity="0.8"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Text="ARC3000MAP Discovered."
      Visibility="{Binding DeviceDiscoveryString7, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
      />



        <Button
      Grid.Row="2"    
      Width="150"
      Content="Let's Discover"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
      Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" 
      Style="{StaticResource AppButton}"
      IsEnabled="{Binding IsDiscoverButtonEnable}" 

      />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am also attaching the screenshot:[image: I think there is an issue with the constructor but dont know the exact problem.]

Can anyone explain me where i am doing something wrong??Any help would be very grateful to me.

Comment: try narrow down the culprit, click on "view detail" in the message box. find which control caused that exception.

Comment: See the `View Detail` and *`Inner Exception`*.

Comment: {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Cannot find resource named 'AppButton'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Comment: Check resource for `Let's Discover` button, the error appears here: `Style="{StaticResource AppButton}"`. Do you have a style for him, and where he is?

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev..Great your answer worked ..i forgot the 's' in 'AppButton' ;)

Comment: Screenshots of exceptions are more than useless.  If you look, there is a link on the exception dialog that will copy all exception details to the clipboard. Use that link to get the details you need to paste into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime `XamlParseException` is in most cases an exception thrown from inside the constructor. See the `View Detail` and *Inner Exception* section.

In your case, check resource for `Let's Discover` Button, the error appears here:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2"    
        Width="150"
        Content="Let's Discover"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" 
        Style="{StaticResource AppButton}" <!-- Here -->
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsDiscoverButtonEnable}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the access modifier to "Public". Double click the Resources.resx file and change the access modifier from Internal to Public.